# Demonstration with fitch notation and quantifiers

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm tryng to demonstrate with fitch notation this:

{∀x (A(x) ↔ B(x)), ∀x (A(x))} |= ∀x (B(x))

Here what I tried: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S5Zy.png

Someone can explain me how i can obtain ∀x (B(x)? Because with the introduction rule of ∀x I can obtain only ∀x (A(x) -> B(x))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the version of a Fitch style proof that you are apparently using, when you get to your line 5, you can go on to just quantify by UQ int.

Thus

$1\quad \forall x(Ax \to Bx)\\
2\quad \forall xAx\\
3\quad\quad d\mid \quad Ad \to Bd\\ 
4\quad\quad \ \mid \quad Ad\\ 
5\quad\quad \ \mid \quad Bd\\ 
6\quad \forall xBx$

Check out your version of the universal quantifier introduction rule which we are appealing to at the last step!

[Actually I don't think this is the most transparent version of the Fitch style proof-layout, although it is [near] Thomason's for example. I prefer to only indent columns when a new, independent, temporary assumption is being made which doesn't follow from what's gone before, e.g. as when starting a conditional proof, or making an assumption for reductio. So even in a Fitch-style natural deduction system where you indent to the right everytime you make a new assumption, and track back to the left when you eventually discharge that assumption, I'd prefer to write this proof simply as

$1\quad \forall x(Ax \to Bx)\\
2\quad \forall xAx\\
3\quad\ Ad \to Bd\\ 
4\quad Ad\\ 
5\quad Bd\\ 
6\quad \forall xBx$

Since, whatever $d$ picks out, (3) and (4) follow from (1) and (2) without further ado. And (6) follows from (5) as (5) depends on no special premisses about $d$.]

Comment: I understand all your demostration and I agree that is more simple. But there is one thing that i don't understand:

Which rule you use in 6. 

In 3 you have the ∀ elimination rule from 1, in 4 the ∀ elimination rule from 2, in 5 the → elimination rule from 4 and 3.  

But in 6?

Comment: Ok thank you. I solved, I forgot that there was a second rule for the universal quantifier introduction rule.

Comment: The problem with not indenting on a universal context is that existential quantification rules become more troublesome, because after all you need some way of distinguishing between names for an existing object and names for universally quantified objects that may not exist. (See http://www.sfu.ca/~jeffpell/papers/pelletierNDtexts.pdf for a number of variations.)